# PyQGIS: Load in memory layer for processing?

Tags: memory, pyqgis

Executing a plugin, I've got two buffer results, which are both stored in memory. These two polygons should further be merged. How to call the in memory buffers for the merge processing?
`

```
def geoprocessing(self):

    # get paths
    input_file_1 = self.ui.txt_input_file_1.text()
    input_file_2 = self.ui.txt_input_file_2.text()
    output_file = self.ui.txt_output.text()

    # get distances
    dis_1 = self.ui.txt_input_distance_1.text()
    dis_2 = self.ui.txt_input_distance_2.text()

    # define output buffers
    output_buffer_1 = 'memory:buffer1'
    output_buffer_2 = 'memory:buffer2'

    # buffer processing
    exe_dict = {input_file_1:[dis_1, output_buffer_1], input_file_2:[dis_2, output_buffer_2]}
    for file in exe_dict:
        processing.runAndLoadResults('native:buffer', {'INPUT': file, 'DISTANCE': exe_dict[file][0], 'SEGMENTS': 25, 'DISSOLVE': False, 'OUTPUT': exe_dict[file][1]})

    # merge processing
    processing.runAndLoadResults('native:mergevectorlayers', {'LAYERS': [output_buffer_1, output_buffer_2], 'OUTPUT': output_file})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to assign the layer to a variable, then add it to a list, e.g.:

```
buffer_layers_list = []
for file in exe_dict:
    buffer_layer = processing.run('native:buffer', {'INPUT': file, 'DISTANCE': exe_dict[file][0], 'SEGMENTS': 25, 'DISSOLVE': False, 'OUTPUT': exe_dict[file][1]})['OUTPUT']
    buffer_layers_list.append(buffer_layer)
```

Then add that list in place of the list you are using already.